# What's the proper way to add one-to-many relationships across tables when submitting form data of an object in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have the following, simplified, schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('lasers','dinosaurs','space') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

A photo can have none, one, or many categories associated with it.

In the form, the categories are represented by checkboxes as this input type matches the model of "none, one, or many" selections.

Here are my questions:

1. With the CakePHP FormHelper, his there a way to display the checkboxes for each of the enum values?
2. Can all of this data be handled by the framework and inserted correctly into both tables on a save() saveAll() call when the form is submitted? Or am I going to have to do a bit of pre processing/custom scripting?
3. Is it possible to integrate these relationships so they can be sorted/paginated/etc. when the data is fetched. E.g. Would I be able to sort/filter the photos that belong to category 'lasers'?
4. Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CakePHP does not support natively enums so you need to fetch them manually. You can then use the Form helper as follows (untested):

   ```php
   echo $this->Form->input('Category.id', array(
       'type' => 'select',
       'multiple' => 'checkbox',
       'options' => $categories, // id => name array
   ));
   ```
2. Using [`saveAssociated()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) is recommened, it will automatically add the `photo_id` to the categories as they are saved.
3. You can filter by adding pagination conditions, but sorting is more complicated seeing as photos can have multiple categories.
4. Unless you are sure the categories will not change you're better off using a [Has And Belongs To Many](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) relationship.